# How would I get multiple results from a MySQL table?

Tags: java, mysql

Say I have 2 columns, the first one is ID and the second one is colour.

How would I search for a specific colour and get all of the id's that are in the same row as the colour?

How would I turn the results into an array?

I know how to do a simple string.

```java
try {
    PreparedStatement ps = plugin.SQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM playerinfo WHERE COLOUR = ?");
    ps.setString(1, colour);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    int id = 0;
    if (rs.next()) {
        id = rs.getInt("ID");
        return id;
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is what it should look like

```
id colour
 1 **red**
 2 blue
 3 green
 4 **red**
 5 **red**
 6 blue


 **red** = highlighted (but we don't know why)
```

Comment: just for the clarification you need to search for particular record and get all the ids associated with that record
like red has 1,4, and 5

Comment: @DoctorWho yes, that is correct

Comment: I would just do a simple where statement:

SELECT 
   id
FROM
    colourtable
WHERE
    colour = 'red';

Comment: @timmmmmb: I agree with your answer. If you answer a question, use the "Your Answer" option. Comments are for comments.

Comment: @timmmmmb There is a complete SELECT in the referenced code - obviously asker just dont know how to make some kind of collection from it

Comment: @Gyro OP edited the question  with code they did not provide at the beginning: they're doing a mess. 2 answers apply to the original question

Comment: @fantaghirocco I am sorry, this is my first post and I had a lot of oversight

Comment: @UberSuperBoss there's no problem :D but this obviously tricks the answerers and should be avoided next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
try (java.sql.Connection conn = plugin.SQL.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM playerinfo WHERE COLOUR = ?");) {
    ps.setString(1, colour);
    java.util.ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        ids.add(rs.getInt(1));
    }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure that you close the `PreparedStatement` and the `Connection`.
- Each call to method `next()` (in `ResultSet`) will return the next row in the result set. Extract the ID from the row and add it to the `ArrayList`.
- If you want an array, rather than `ArrayList`, you can convert `ArrayList` to array with one of the `toArray` methods in class [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Maybe this will also help:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right,

You should use this :

```
SELECT ID
FROM your_table
WHERE COLOUR = 'red';
```